# Flask `before_request` context functions on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Flask context classes and functions on Google Cloud Functions. Here's simple code of what I'm trying to do:

```
import time
from flask import request, jsonify, g

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.start = time.time()

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    if ((response.json) and (response.response) and (200 <= response.status_code < 300)):
        response.json['execution_time'] = time.time() - g.start
        response.set_data(bytes(json.dumps(response.json), 'utf-8'))
    return response

def hello_world(request):
    response = jsonify({"status": "success", "message": "Hello World!"})
    response.status_code = 200
    return response
```

I've tried removing `app.` and just using `@before_request`, but that doesn't seem to work. Any idea if this is supported?

Also, yes, I know that I could just add an `execution_time` parameter to each of my responses, but a) it would be nice to set it globally, and b) there are other use cases for the `before_request` and `after_request` functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to operate outside of the function context in Cloud Functions. Cloud Functions do not have access to the underlying `app`.

You may want to consider using [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) instead, which would let you define a complete Flask `app` and use `@app.before_request` and `@app.after_request`.

Comment: Thanks, Dustin! Yeah, I'm using Cloud Run for a few other things, and I was moving some code from there to Cloud Functions to make them more efficient. That was the one part of my code I couldn't get to work. It's not a huge deal, but I thought it was worth asking just to make sure.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by "more efficient" -- Cloud Functions and Cloud Run offer very similar efficiencies.

Comment: Well, there's quite a bit more overhead with Cloud Run vs Cloud Functions. While Cloud Run is quite fast, cutting out the fat and using simple functions on the Flask backend provided by Cloud Functions is bound to be faster and more efficient.

Comment: Behind the scenes, Cloud Functions is wrapping your function in a Flask app and deploying it into an environment that is very similar to App Engine / Cloud Run. The efficiencies are mostly around minimizing complexity for the developer, not runtime or memory, etc.

Comment: Oh, I know - I understand that. However, there are still a few more architectural layers required to launch a container on Cloud Run than to execute a standalone function on Cloud Functions. Minimal? Sure. Worth taking into consideration? Absolutely.